# Pass a Value from EJB to JPA using session

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb, ejb-3.0

I have to upgrade my code for a multi tenant environment.

I am planning to do the same using Hibernate filters.But I dont want my application code to change for passing the tenant Id in each method.

I want some way to get the tenant id directly in dao via session or some other thing.

Comment: Did you consider `ThreadLocal`s?

Comment: what are threadlocal. I dont think we have such as all thread management is done by app server it self

Comment: `ThreadLocal` is a way to pass information through application layers, like thread variable. You attach tenant id as thread local to a running thread, and it can be read from thread as long as the thread is active. There are lots of online resources, check it out.

Comment: Also, here are some helpful links https://gist.github.com/rponte/0b9f8736103a70390283
http://www.slideshare.net/seges/multitenancy-in-java